# Enforce merge branch approval for TFS

Tags: tfs, merge, release-management, tfs-code-review

i work in a SQL Development Environment.
We have three branches namely DEV, TEST and LIVE.

Whenever a developer did something and wants to deploy on Test System i need a mechanism within TFS that enforces him to do a code review.

I know this can be done by enforcing a code review check-in policy. 
But I don't want to trigger a code review with every check-in but more whenever somebody merges to TEST branch.

Think of it more as an approval enforcement. I want that TFS is requesting a code reviewe whenever somebody branches into a different branch. The best scenario is that i can specify the branches that trigger this behaviour.

Comment: Have you specify the path in the Code Review Check-in policy as I mentioned? Is it working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code Review Check-in policy can specify a path to apply this policy to, so you can only apply this policy to your TEST branch:

[image]

By the way, if you use Git team project in TFS 2017 or VSTS, you can enable branch policies to require code reviews for a branch. More information, check: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/branch-policies